# How to override ostream << operator for already defined type

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I'm currently working on a port of an existing library which makes use of ostream to write to a terminal.

The ostream was derived as part of the port.

The ostream derivative class used is defined as so:

```
class owstream: public std::ostream {
public:
    CTerminal * output;
    giac::context * contextptr;
    owstream(CTerminal *, giac::context * contextptr , int = 0);
    virtual ~owstream();
};
```

This is used to output some data, typically integers and doubles.

The problem is that the platform I'm working on has a buggy double print routine that causes kernel crash.

So in some cases, if I do:

```
ostream* mystream = new ostream(...);
(*mystream) << 1.23456
```

kaboom

so, I tried to override the << operator for certain type, like so:

```
ostream* GetStream() { return = new MyOStream(...); }

....

ostream* mystream = GetStream()
mystream << 1.23456;
```

Unfortunately, the operator<< member in ostream isn't virtual so if I created an overridden operator<< member would never be called.

I tried to extend it with something like:

```
class owstream: public std::ostream {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, double val);
  public:
    CTerminal * output;
    giac::context * contextptr;
    owstream(CTerminal *, giac::context * contextptr , int = 0);
    virtual ~owstream();
};

extern std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, double val);
```

But this causes compilation error in regards to operator << being ambiguous, as obviously this is a type already handle by the base iostream class.

I'm starting to wonder if this is at all possible.

How would you implement the << operator to override the behaviour when given a particular, already handled type ?

The aim being able to do something like:

```
cout << 1.234567
```

not crashing (I obviously wouldn't be using cout, but GetStream() as defined above, could very well return cout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three problems with your current approach/implementation.

**Problem #1**

Even if you were to successfully get it to use `std::ostream` as the first parameter and return value it would not work correctly. The problem stems mainly from returning an `ostream` from the overloaded `operator<<`. After the first value has been sent to the `owstream` all subsequent values get sent to the returned `ostream`. This puts you right back where you started with the original problem. In order to for this to work properly you need to take `owstream` as the first parameter and return an `owstream` in the overloaded `operator<<`.

**Problem #2**

Another problem is `owstream` is implicitly convertible to `std::ostream`. Depending on how `owstream` is used in your project there is a possibility that the overloads you provide may not make a difference in certain situations. For instance if an object of type `owstream` is passed to a function that accepts a `std::ostream` you may end up encountering the problem you are currently experiencing. You can prevent this from happening by using `private` inheritance. This will prevent any implicit use of `owstream` as a `std::ostream`. Using `private` inheritance also has the benefit of preventing you from unknowingly using functions in `std::ostream` which may lead you back to your original problem. For instances where a `std::ostream` is absolutely necessary you can use an accessor function to explicitly retrieve a reference to it.

**Problem #3**

The last issue is that `std::ostream` includes an overload of `operator<<` that handles `std::ostream` specific IO manipulators such as `std::endl`. If you do not provide an overload to specifically handle these the one in `std::ostream` gets used and once again you end up right back where you started. If you use `private` inheritance described above and do not provide an overload to handle the manipulators it will fail to compile.

---

**Solution**

The solution below is similar to the one provided by [JRG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17133802/845568) and includes the accessor function and overloads for `double`, `float`, and `std::ostream` IO manipulators. It is a complete working example and uses the stream buffer from `std::cout` for simplicity. I included the overload for `float` as the deficient library implementation may a similar issue with them. It also uses private inheritance to prevent implicit conversions to `std::ostream`.

I tested it on VC++10 and GCC 4.7.2. You may need to make some adjustments depending on how compliant your compiler and libraries are.

```
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class owstream : private std::ostream
{
public:
    owstream(std::streambuf* sb)
        : std::ostream(sb)
    {}

    // Template based operator...ohhhhhh ahhhhh.
    template <typename T>
    friend owstream& operator<<(owstream&, const T&);

    // Additional overload to handle ostream specific io manipulators 
    friend owstream& operator<<(owstream&, std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&));

    // Accessor function to get a reference to the ostream
    std::ostream& get_ostream() { return *this; }
};


template <typename T>
inline owstream&
operator<<(owstream& out, const T& value)
{
    static_cast<std::ostream&>(out) << value;
    return out;
}

//  overload for double
template <>
inline owstream&
operator<<(owstream& out, const double& value)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << value;
    return out << ss.str();
}

//  overload for float
template <>
inline owstream&
operator<<(owstream& out, const float& value)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << value;
    return out << ss.str();
}

//  overload for std::ostream specific io manipulators
inline owstream&
operator<<(owstream& out, std::ostream& (*func)(std::ostream&))
{
    static_cast<std::ostream&>(out) << func;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    owstream ows(std::cout.rdbuf());

    ows << std::endl;
    ows << "hello " << 1.0 << " " << 2.0f << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion, but in my case it would be use like so:`    owstream ows(std::cout.rdbuf());
    std::ostream& ss = ows.get_ostream();

    ss << std::endl;
    ss << "hello " << 1.0 << " " << 2.0f << std::endl;
` and none of the overridden operator are now called :(

Comment: Doing `std::ostream& ss = ows.get_ostream()` and then using `ss << value` is _not_ going to work because the operators are non-virtual members of `ostream` (in a conforming implementation anyway). Your best option here is going to be replacing all usage of `ostream` with `owstream` in the project. Using `private` inheritance will definitely help here because it will prevent the implicit conversion from being performed. This will cause the compile to fail until everything has been refactored to use it.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
template <typename T>
owstream& operator<<(owstream&, const T&);

template <typename T>
inline owstream&
operator<<(owstream& os, const T& val)
{
   std::ostream& stdos = static_cast<std::ostream&>(os);
   stdos << val;
   return os;
}

template <>
inline owstream&
operator<<(owstream& os, const double& val)
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << val;
   os << ss.str();
   return os;
}
```