# Deriving std::ofstream and overloading operator<<

Tags: c++, inheritance, std

How to derive from the std::ofstream class, to add a few actions before writing to a file? 
In other words, replacing code like

```
int main()
{
   std::ofstream file("file.txt");
   file << "something" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

by

```
class MyFile : public std::ofstream
{
   MyFile(std::string filename) : std::ofstream(filename) {}

   ??? operator<< ???   <-- HERE1
   {
      // 1. do some stuff with the input
      // 2. if wanted,
      // flush it to the base class operator<<
   }
};

class MyFileC
{
private:
   std::ofstream intern_os;
public:
   MyFileC(std::string filename) : intern_os(filename) {}

   MyFileC& operator<<( input ???   <-- HERE2  )
   {


          // 1. do some stuff with the input
          // e.g (a) IF the input is a std::string,
          // THEN, if it contains "signal",
          // OnSignal();
          // or (b) if file size is too big, clear it ...
          // 2. Flush it (for all possible types):

      intern_os << input;
   }
};

int main()
{
    MyFile file("file2.txt"); // (or with MyFileC)
    file << "something" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

where we could for example filter on-the-fly before writing etc.

What to put in the *???* lines to enjoy all the existing std::ofstream.operator<<(), with our personal addings, please?

- *HERE1* : more elegant, with inheritance approach;
  or if impossible (after the comments below),
- *HERE2* : what type to give to pass "whatever that could passed to the internal std::ofstream" (strings, ints, ...)

Comment: You can't, really. `operator<<` was not declared `virtual` in the base, so anyone using your `MyFile` through a reference/pointer to an `ofstream` will not call your derived `operator<<`. Generally, the answer to '_How do I inherit from an `std::` class_' is '_Don't_'. I mean, you probably could do it, and it might even seem close enough to working - _iff_ you always use it as a `MyFile` - but then you would just be exploiting the fact that the derived `operator<<` would _hide_ the base `operator<<`, not _override_ it, and this seems very brittle.

Comment: Deriving from a standard library stream is not recommended. The usual approach is to replace the underlying stream buffer with a class derived from `std::streambuf` if you have to. That said, this looks like a great opportunity to practice [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and wrap the underlying stream with your own class and functions.

Comment: @underscore_d Oh.. Then must use composition, to embed a std::ofstream in the MyFile etc ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override ostream << operator for already defined type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132289/how-to-override-ostream-operator-for-already-defined-type)

Comment: Well it depends on what you want to keep from `operator <<`, and what is the *stuff to to with input*.  If you only want to process `std::strings` and `const char *` then defining your own operators on a class *containing* a `std::ofstream` is probably the way to go. On the opposite, if you want to be able to accept any class for which an overriden `ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const T&)` exists, you should use a custom `std::streambuf` in a subclass of `std::basic_ostream`. You do not give enough details for a more precise answer...

Comment: @SergeBallesta It is more your second option. The idea is to have an abstract "file" that could do _all what the std::ofstream could_, but with some actions like verify the size of the file, etc

Comment: If you give an example of those *actions* and when they are expected to happen (at open/close time, on some *special* characters, or what else) you could get better answers...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator<<` isn’t intended to be overwritten by derived stream classes. Instead, you should override [`std::basic_streambuf::overflow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/overflow) and/or [`std::basic_streambuf::xsputn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/sputn).

`overflow` in particular is called internally whenever the buffer overflows. If you want to provide your own buffering, you can do this by initialising the stream pointers via [`std::basic_streambuf::setp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/setp) inside your overridden stream class. The links come with examples of how to do that.

There’s just one cosmetic problem here: these are all *buffer* methods. You want to override `std::fstream`, which is a *stream* class, not a [*buffer* class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf). What you need to do is therefore twofold:

1. Override [`std::basic_filebuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf%60) as described above.
2. Use [`std::fstream::rdbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) to set the associated buffer of a file stream object to an instance of your overridden file buffer class. You can do this either on an instance of the existing `std::fstream` or on a custom subclass of that type.